# How can I dynamically attach an event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Window (a div) in React that I want to be resizable. Using the `onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}` interface I can implement it, but the problem is that those handlers will only be called as long as I stay inside the div.

When you resize an element, you often move the cursor outside the div to indicate that you want it to grow. Therefore, I want to attach a global listener to onMouseMove in the onMouseDown event so that I can achieve that.

How would I go about that, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, attaching event handlers to the window's onmousemove and onmouseup (to detach the dynamically added event handlers) events works well, then the events fire even when the mouse moves outside the window.

Easy enough to do with `addEventListener` inside React's onmousedown event.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way to do this in React alone? I must use another library?

Comment: That's correct.  You don't need jQuery, but you do need to attach the event listeners manually using the DOM.  React only deals with declarative bindings in the component tree, anything outside the root of the tree is outside the scope of React.

Comment: Why bothering using *yet* another library for such a straightforward thing: document.addEventListener("mousemove", myFunction); ... you can't be more cross-browser than this

Comment: When this answer was written, supporting IE8 was still common. Dropping IE8 support and using addEventListener directly is a much more reasonable option today, so I've updated the answer. Anyone supporting legacy browsers will know to use an alternative if required.

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer suggests that you hack a solution around `React` (using `jQuery` or other libraries). And one of the comments mentions you can do it via `DOM` manipulation (still outside of React).

While technically correct, I would like to suggest a better approach. You're already using `React`, so instead of fighting the framework, try to embrace it and think of a solution inside of it.
(Note: This solution has a limitation - if the cursor leaves the browser window, the MouseMove event will be interrupted. If you need to be able to capture the event even in such cases, then consider the other answers)

So you have your `window` `React` component that you'd like to be resizeable. It lives inside some other `div`, lets call it `windowContainer`.

- Implement the `windowContainer` as a React component.
- `windowContainer` can have a state that describes the frame of the `window` (let's call it `windowFrame`).
- Inside the `window` define a `onMouseDown` (presumably in some `handle` UI element) that tells the `windowContainer` that resizing should start.
- Inside the `windowContainer`, in an `onMouseMove` you can calculate the mouse position changes and refresh the state's `windowFrame`. Your `window` will adopt the new frame.
- Also inside the `windowContainer`, you can detect `onMouseUp` at which point you'll disconnect the `onMouseMove` event.

Some additional info that might help people looking to implement this solution:

When I say 'connect' / 'disconnect' `onMouseMove` event listener, you need to think of this in the React declarative way. So for example the way to do it is to have a state property called `isResizingWindow` and then in the `render()` block you have something like:

```
<div onMouseMove={  this.state.isResizingWindow  ?  (event) => this.handle_onMouseMove(event) : undefined } </div>
```

Also make sure you're working with the `React` events, not the `DOM` events. Especially if using `TypeScript`, make sure your definition looks like this:

```
handle_onMouseMove(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>)
{
    // Here is where the frame calculation and setState goes
}
```

Comment: Attaching event handlers like this to a large container div will work as long as the mouse pointer stays within the container div. The events on the top level window object are special though, they allow handling the event wherever the mouse is on the screen, so they still work if the mouse is moved outside the browser window. That's why the accepted answer suggests using non-React APIs, since React doesn't render the window object.

Comment: @Douglas , I agree that the original question could be interpreted like that as well, so I've changed my answer to reflect this.

The way I understood the question is that the user has a component called "Window" that lives inside the browser window and that should be resizeable.

So for anyone stumbling upon this question -if you need to be able to capture the mouse event even when it leaves the browser window, then consider the other solutions. Otherwise, consider the pure React solution I suggested.